# Javascript Text Overlay - Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a simple javascript function to display different text in a slide show effect, which works well.

However, there is a delay before and after the cycle, which im trying to eliminate, without any success, even when modifying the delay value. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(1000)
            .fadeOut(1000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();
</script>
```

html is simply

> `<p class="quotes">text here</p> etc`

Any help would be great

Comment: Something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/g9z9b8fz/)**?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I  dont see anything difference apart from delay removed?

Comment: Exactly where are you seeing the "delay"?  In both @GuruprasadRao and [my version](http://jsfiddle.net/peogo8nk/), there's no delay before or after.  (apart from the obvious `.delay` in the middle).   Question: when you run my fiddle version, do you still see a delay?

Comment: I suspect this is a perceived delay due to fadein/fadeout using a `linear` easing (the jquery default).  So the end 10-15% look the same to you so it looks like it's not changing during that part.   You could include `jquery-ui` and try a different [easing](https://jqueryui.com/easing/), but I couldn't see one that would give you what you want (the opposite of `swing` - fast at the ends, slow in the middle.

Comment: You said you want to eliminate `delay` right? how exactly..?

Comment: Its an error my side, further down the page im using a similar system, which also uses the class "quotes". This caused  the delay in the one in question as it had to wait for the other to finished. I simply added another JQuery to handle the other one and the delay had disappeared!

Comment: Thanks both for assistance!

Comment: Glad you found the issue.  Always worth creating a [minimal repeatable verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version.