# How do I fade in & fade out 3 divs with other divs inside that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have the following HTML & CSS.

HTML

```
<DIV class="newsPic"></DIV>
<DIV class="newsPicTwo"></DIV>
<DIV class="newsPicThree"></DIV>
```

CSS

```
.newsPic {
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
}

.newsPicTwo {
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
}

.newsPicThree {
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
}
```

Is it possible to fade in the DIV "newsPic". Fade it out. Then fade in "newsPicTwo" etc... and then loop after it's finished? Is it also possible to add as many other DIVS / content inside the "newsPic", "newsPicTwo" etc and for it to all fade accordingly.

Comment: Yes, all of this is possible, but you need to show that you've tried something. SO isn't a site where you just come with a request for people to do work for you.

Comment: please google such questions.

Comment: Or even search in SO: (though you'd be forgiven for not finding this one that does exactly what you want): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843106/javascript-text-overlay-delay

Comment: show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible? Yes!

How? Through JS (DOM, animate) and with a little CSS perhaps (transition, keyframes)

Comment: How does this help? `:/`

Comment: This is a lot better help, believe me.

Comment: Negative motivation, yes. But depends.

Comment: I gave him the areas of study that he needs to look at.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to do.

1. Keep one single class: `.newsPic`.
2. Create a parent, say: `newsPics`.
3. Use a jQuery Slider plugin like `bxSlider`.

In a simple way, you can do something like a **Ticker**:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.newsPics').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 1,
    mode: 'vertical',
    maxSlides: 1,
    slideWidth: 500,
    slideHeight: 200,
    slideMargin: 10,
    ticker: true,
    speed: 6000,
    pause: 1000
  });
});
```

```css
.newsPic {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #99f;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.css" />

<div class="newsPics">
  <div class="newsPic">One</div>
  <div class="newsPic">Two</div>
  <div class="newsPic">Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: Pretty presumptuous to say about yourself when not having taught anybody anything here.

Comment: @Shikkediel I just said a way to do.

Comment: That's what Google's for, the great almighty 'teacher'.

Comment: LoL. Yeah.. Accepted buddy.